# $Q(Q)$ is not complete while it is a finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Theorem: Every finite dimensional normed space is complete.

$Q$ is a finite-dimensional normed space over $Q$ with the norm $||x||=$ $|x|$. But it is not complete.
We have a Cauchy sequence $(1+1/n)^n$ tending to $e\in Q^c$.

Comment: normed spaces are either $\mathbb C$-linear or $\mathbb R$-linear spaces, by definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually a normed vector space is a vector space over the field $K$, where $K= \mathbb R$ or $K= \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 6):

You are right!  In a strange book where "normed space" is defined for fields like $\mathbb Q$ with its usual metric, the theorem should be stated:  *Every finite-dimensional normed space over a complete field is complete.*  (I am not aware of such a strange book, however.  I have seen "normed space" defined for $p$-adic number fields, which are complete.  And maybe an exercise or two with incomplete field, showing why it is not useful in that case.)