# Finite dimensional topological vector space non complete

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I know that all finite-dimension **Hausdorff** topological vector spaces are complete.

I would like to know if there is a example of a topological vector space (over the real or complex numbers) that is **not Hausdorff** and is also **not complete**.

I tried to build a counter example, but I couldn't. First, I tried to put the topology generated by the basis $\mathscr{B}=\{(-a,a)\times \mathbb{R}: a>0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this space is complete. Then I tried to take a known example of non-complete space, so I chose the product topology with infinite copies of $\mathbb{R}$, but this space has no finite dimension and is Hausdorff.

Comment: [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401074/qq-is-not-complete-while-it-is-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space)

Comment: If the topology is generated by a semi-norm as in your example you can just quotient out the null space to get a finite dimensional Hausdorff space which must then be complete. That will show completeness of the original space. Whats left is to see whether every finite dimensional topological vector space is generated by semi-norms, that statement seems true.

Comment: @SahibaArora I assume he is working with real or complex vector spaces, otherwise the theorem he stated could fail.

Comment: @SahibaArora The spaces they are discussing are Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @VictorHugo Hence I didn't claim it is a duplicate.

Comment: As @Anonymous said, I am assuming that my space is a complex or a real vector space.

Comment: I haven't worked out the details, but I suspect that the only topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ which make it a TVS are the indiscrete topology and the standard topology, and consequently, every finite dimensional TVS is isomorphic to a product of standard $\mathbb{R}$'s and indiscrete $\mathbb{R}$'s which will be complete. But someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be a TVS and denote with $N$ the closure of $\{0\}$, this is again a vector sub-space as it is the closure of a vector sub-space. Further, every open neighbourhood of $0$ contains all of $N$ (and so does every open neighbourhood of any point in $N$). I'll carry this last comment out in more detail, suppose $x,y\in N$, if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ not containing $y$ you have that $U-y$ is an open neighbourhood of $x-y$ not containing $0$. But $x-y\in N$ and $N$ is the closure of $\{0\}$ and every open neighbourhood of points in $N$ must intersect $\{0\}$, contradiction.

Now $V/N$ is a quotient of a topological group by a closed sub-group, hence it is Hausdorff by general facts. In other words $V/N$ is a Hausdorff TVS, since it is also finite dimensional it is complete.

So let $x_\alpha$ be a Cauchy net in $V$, meaning that for any neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ you have a $\gamma$ so that $x_\alpha - x_\beta\in U$ for all $\alpha, \beta ≥\gamma$. By continuity of the projection map you have that $[x_\alpha]$ has the same property in $V/N$, hence admits a limit $[x]$ by completeness. We will now see that any lift $x$ of $[x]$ is a limit of $x_\alpha$.

As we have seen $[x_\alpha - x]$ eventually lies in every neighbourhood of $[0]$, meaning that $x_\alpha-x+N$ eventually lies in $U+N$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $0$. But by what we have seen in the first paragraph $U\supseteq N$ hence $x_\alpha - x$ eventually lies in $U$. This shows $x_\alpha\to x$.

Comment: Using your idea I did a proof using filters. Could you check if the proof is correct?

Comment: Looks good. Possibly there are too many neighbourhoods appearing so it gets a bit confusing and you use $V$ for filter elements and for the original space, but the argument looks correct. (You also have the inclusion $\phi(\mathscr F)\subset \mathscr F_{V/N}(\overline x)$ the other way around, as $\phi(\mathscr F)$ should refine the neighbourhood filter.)

Comment: I fixed this problem in the notation.

Comment: I think $U\supseteq N$ implies $x_\alpha-x$ eventually lies in $U+U$. Then every neighborhood of $0$ contains a neighborhood of the form $U+U$, since the addition is continuous at 0.

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $\mathscr{F}_E(y)$ be the filter of neighborhoods of a point $y$ in the TVS $E$.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional TVS and denote with $N$ the closure of $\{0\}$, this is again a vector sub-space as it is the closure of a vector sub-space. Further, every open neighbourhood of $0$ contains all of $N$.

Now $V/N$ is a quotient of a topological group by a closed sub-group, hence it is Hausdorff space. In other words $V/N$ is a Hausdorff TVS, since it is also finite dimensional it is complete.

So let $\mathscr{F}$ be a Cauchy filter in $V$. By continuity of the projection map we have that $\phi(\mathscr{F})$ is a Cauchy filter in $V/N$, hence admits a limit $\overline{x}$ by completeness. We will now see that any lift $x$ of $\overline{x}$ is a limit of $\mathscr{F}$ in $V$.

Let $Z \in \mathscr{F}_{V/N}(\overline{x})$, since $\mathscr{F}_{V/N}(\overline{x}) \subset \phi(\mathscr{F})$, there exists $F \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $\phi(F) \subset Z$. Therefore, $F \subset \phi^{-1}(\phi(F)) \subset \phi^{-1}(Z)$, which implies that $\phi^{-1}(Z) \in \mathscr{F}$.

We claim that $\mathscr{F}_V(x) \subset \mathscr{F}$. Let $U+x \in \mathscr{F}_V(x)$ and consider $W \in \mathscr{F}_V(0)$ such that $W+W \subset U$. Define $Z=\phi(W+x)=\phi(W)+\overline{x} \in \mathscr{F}_{V/N}(\overline{x})$. As we have seen  $\phi^{-1}(Z) \in \mathscr{F}$, that is, $W+x+N=\phi^{-1}(\phi(W+x)) \in \mathscr{F}$. Observing that $W+x+N \subset W+x+W \subset U+x$, we obtain $U+x \in \mathscr{F}$ as desired.