# Does homeomorphism of finite dimension topological vector space implies completeness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be finite dimension topological vector space,that **linear** homeomorphic to complete vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Euclidean topology.  Prove $X$ is complete also.

We know $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, and $X$ is finite dimension.To show the completeness I do as follows:

First since $X$ is metrilizable(due to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is metrilizable), we just need to check Cauchy sequence converge. Just treat $(x_n)\in X$ likes $(\bar{x}_i)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ which complete the proof.

Is my proof correct?Linear is vital in the proof correct?

Comment: Completeness is only defined when a metric has been given. But you only said that $X$ is a finite dimensional topological vector space. What metric did you intend to give on $X$?

Comment: @Lee Mosher The metric is not fixed.I think it does not depend on the chosen metric since the homeomophism is also linear isomorphism?

Comment: We know $\bar{x}_n$  is also Cauchy (by linear map )hence converge to  $\bar{x}$,now we can show $x_n \to x$ in TVS $X$

Comment: @Chrystomath thanks in the notes the proof that completeness is preserved under linear homeomorphism for TVS is not provided

Comment: @yili Corollary 3.1.5? Completeness is not preserved in general, but every (hausdorff) finite dimensional t.v.s. is complete. By preserving dimension, the linear homeomorphism preserves completeness.

Comment: @yili In general a homeomorphism does not preserve completeness, eg $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. But $X$ has a linear structure as well. The question emphasizes that the homeomorphism is *linear*.

Comment: @Chrystomath  Sorry for the elementary question does "linear homeomorphism" preserve completeness,I have proved it,but I don't know whether I made a false proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample, which highlights the fact that completeness is *not* independent of the metric.

Take $X = \mathbb R$, which is a 1-dimensional topological vector space. Use the homeomorphism $f : \mathbb R \to (-\pi/2,\pi/2) $ given by $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$ to transport the metric from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ back to $\mathbb R$, obtaining $d(x,y) = \left|f(x) - f(y)\right|$. Any sequence $(x_n)$ that approaches $+\infty$ is nonconvergent in $\mathbb R$, but it is a Cauchy sequence because $(f(x_n))$ approaches $\pi/2$ and therefore $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence.

What this counterexample highlights is that the *metric space* notion of completeness is not quite what one wants for purposes of studying topological vector spaces; this may be where your confusion lies.

Take a look at the [wikipedia page on topological vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space), particularly the section on [metrizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Metrizability) and the section on [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Completeness_and_uniform_structure), and you will see that the *topological vector space* notion of completeness is a somewhat different and a somewhat subtler than the metric space notion.

Comment: But I find another post says  all finite-dimension Hausdorff topological vector spaces are complete. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3733938/360262 ?

Comment: We need to check that another topology transform by $f$ compactible with linear structure?

Comment: The issue is not with the topology. The issue is with the choice of metric, as my answer shows. I suggest you read up a bit more about metrics on topological vector spaces; see for example [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Metrizability).

Comment: Also, that other post that is linked in your comment above is not using the "metric space" notion of completeness, i.e. "every Cauchy sequence converges". Instead it is instead using a [special notion of completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Completeness_and_uniform_structure) that is defined only for topological vector spaces.

Comment: I've rewitten my answer a bit to incorporate these last few comments.

Comment: Oh I got it,I use the "completeness" in the sense for any $U_o$ as neiborhood of 0,exist $x_n-x_m \in U_o$.No metric needed,since we know some topology induce by metric need not to make space topological vector space.Some TVS is also not necessarily metrilizable

Comment: That sounds right to me. And, by the way, I liked your question because I learned a little bit more about topological vector spaces myself!